# Xamarin Forms error when compiling in release mode for Android - No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V21.Widget.Design.AppBarLayout'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting the following error when I attempt to compile in release mode to put my application in the Android App Store.  I do not get the error when I compile for debug mode.

I have found references to similar errors.  They seem to revolve around the android support services not matching the Android SDK.  I am running on the Android 28 SDK.  I have updated my google support libraries to the v28.0.0 in NuGet.  I am running in macosx and am using vs mac.

I am quite at a loss on this issue.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

TIA

> ...../obj/Release/lp/40/jl/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml(0,0): Error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V21.Widget.Design.AppBarLayout'. (APT0000)....

Comment: Just as an FYI, I had proguard enabled previously.  I have disabled it, same result.  So, proguard has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: FYI, I was able to successfully compile on Windows.  I'm on my mac and I would like to compile and upload to the play store from here if at all possible.

Comment: Try this. Go to your Android project's properties > Build > General > Compile using Android version: (Target Framework): Set this to the highest version of Android. If that fails try cleaning, restoring Nuget packages and rebuilding your projects. This also happens to me and these suggestions (usually) works.

Comment: Thank @iamlawrencev.  That didn't solve the problem, but I finally did get it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure that I have "solved" the problem completely, but I have at least solved it for the moment.  I kept digging into the output and found a funny character in the custom proguard.cfg information in the build output.  I opened the proguard.cfg file that I had created in notepadd++.  Sure enough, notepadd++ is set to encode with the "UTF-8 with BOM" setting.  I changed that, resaved, rebuilt, and no errors.  I'm going to keep a watchful eye on this, but the problem for the moment is resolved.  Thanks for everyone's input.  It was much appreciated.  :-)